# UILabel Dynamic Font size keep breaking

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, uifont

I Have CollectionViewCell that has only UILabel(Same bounds as cell).
I'm fetching array of fontNames as the CollectionView DataSource  :

```
 func printFonts() {
        let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames()
        for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
            let names = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName as! String)
            fontNames.append(familyName as! String)

        }
    }
```

I'm trying to display this font names in **one** line inside the UILabel , it works in some of the cases but in some not, and i have not idea why.
this is how i "adjust" the font inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` :

```
   cell.lbl_font.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
   cell.lbl_font.numberOfLines = 1
   cell.lbl_font.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
   cell.lbl_font.baselineAdjustment = .AlignCenters
   cell.lbl_font.textAlignment  = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

as well i modified this properties via storyBoard :

[image: desc]

**Result :**

[image: desc]

**UPDATE :**

How do i apply text to the cell. where `lbl_font` is the label inside the cell,
Inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
  let cell : textCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("text_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! textCell
       cell.lbl_font.text = fontNames[indexPath.row]
      cell.lbl_font.font = UIFont(name:fontNames[indexPath.row], size:    cell.lbl_font.font.pointSize)
      cell.lbl_font.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
      cell.lbl_font.numberOfLines = 1
      cell.lbl_font.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
      cell.lbl_font.baselineAdjustment = .AlignCenters
      cell.lbl_font.textAlignment  = NSTextAlignment.Center
      return cell
```

Comment: not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you use auto layout? if co can you show the constraints. How do you create cells and updates its data?

Comment: No, im not using autoLayout. I explained above about the CV DataSource. And i simply want to present text inside UILabel without the three dots(...)/break words that happening like the image above. Plus - Display in in 1 line and not multiline

Comment: but what if the text is too long? how do you want to deal with this? You append the text but it can but far to long to fit the cell

Comment: Thats why i dynamically changes the font size , as you can see in the image above. for 90% precent of the cells it fits correctly , but for some it dosent, for some strange reason

Comment: how do you apply text to the cell. Paste the code, please

Comment: @JulianKról Updated, i really dont understand why does it matter lol. All the relevant code is above

Comment: okay so if you know what matters then good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is minimum font shrink property is available. it shrinks the font size as minimum ratio with the current point size. If the content become more then the ratio of fonts then it will defiantly shows the truncation dots(...) at the end.

For example :

Here I am setting up the property with minimum font scale is 0.4.

[image]

And here you can see different texts applied with the same property.

[image]

In first and second label will adjust the font size because content is less and it adjust as per minimum font scale ratio. but in 3rd the minimum font ratio and the content of the label is does not matched then it will show the dots(...) with truncation.

**For this issue you should know that how mach content should be shown on that label or for batter use you can use multiline label.**

Hope you will get help from the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ashish, as you can see this is exactly what i did. Your third label is exactly what happening to me, how can i fix it that the third label wont break from your example?

Comment: @roimulia brother I already mentioned that : For this issue you should know that how mach content should be shown on that label or for batter use you can use multiline label.  Or change the minimum font ratio

Comment: @roimulia If you change the minimum font ratio to 0.2 then it will again fit with the width :) So we can't judge the minimum font ratio. Hope you are getting. And the font size is also too smaller and it is not good.

Comment: Hey Brother, Thank you for your answers , i'm still having a bit hard time to understand this lol, any chance you have skype?