# UILabel Autoshrink Mal-use?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uilabel, autosize

I Need a label in my UI to hold up to 32 characters  without distorting, so I enabled auto shrink and changed the number of lines to 0:

[image]

heres my label on the IB:

[image]

now when I run the application it runs off the screen:

[image]

how can I make it fit accordingly?

Comment: Try using minimumScaleFactor instead.  Minimum font size is deprecated in iOS 6 onwards.

Comment: Please check the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32155204/3202193 Hope it helps you.

Comment: that didn't have any effect on it @Shripada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]remove constraints first

- give the width 0 and apply width constraints . Click on the constraints change width constraint = to >= after which side you want (left or right) apply top space and (trailing space or leading space) apply two constraints.
- clear the lable text.
- try it and let me know after this wat is th problem.

Comment: what do you mean make the width 0 &  >= to left or right side.. meaning to the superview?

Comment: to super view apply these constraints

Comment: so make the width - superview

Comment: take in consideration that image view frame i also have on the frame

Comment: which side you want to stretch that side no need of constraints

Comment: i dont want to stretch anything, i just want the label to be able to fit 32 characters without it running off the scene. thats why i enabled autoshrink. That label is holding dynamic strings up to 2 characters, so i want the size to shrink depending on the length

Comment: give the either trailing edge or leading edge constraints. if the considerations left side you have image . so from image view leave 5 pixel space that should equl space between image view and lable. lable width i mention in image . after apply width constraints edit like shown in image . if you want apply hight constraints. if it is not solve comment ur skype i will call you

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the number of lines to be `0`, because that will tell the label to use *any* number of lines that it needs. You also have to constrain the label's right edge to its superview's right edge, because without that, it'll run off the right side, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

You are on right direction. Set minimum font size and maximum font size of the label and not need to truncate characters, not need to set number of lines. Autoshrink definitely works.